# How to make Chrome recognize one word queries as a search not a url

Tags: google-chrome

When you type a single word, in other words no spaces in a search, Chrome asks you if you meant a url. How do I change this? v. 12.0.712.0

Comment: When I use Chrome and put only one word in to the omnibar, I get a Google search.

Comment: Xe is talking about what Chrome does _after that_ (in certain circumstances, depending from one's machine's name lookup settings), which is to display a push-down "`Did you mean to go to http://wibble ?`" banner.

Answer (score 4):

Your DNS is taking that word and telling Chrome that its a website. So Chrome asks you if you meant to visit it. Chances are, if you did visit that site, you'd end up on your ISP's not found page.

The only way I've found to rectify this is turning off the "web service" option in the options and changing your DNS to Google's public DNS

http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html

Comment: Exactly. I switched my DNS from my ISP to Google's. I'm no longer prompted if that is the page I indeed meant to visit. http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an issue with your ISP. However, if you prefix your searches with a question mark, like `?google.com`, the question mark is telling Chrome always do a search. So in that example we will end up Googling google.com rather than going to it.

I think the best you can do is just prefix it with a ? character.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the word by itself and press enter:  `wibble` then it will do a search for the word **wibble**.

To connect to a server named **wibble** put a slash at the end of the word. For example:    `wibble/`

This will attempt to connect to `http://wibble/`