# How can I disable the "URL suggestion" feature of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Chrome recognize one word queries as a search not a url](https://superuser.com/questions/266049/how-to-make-chrome-recognize-one-word-queries-as-a-search-not-a-url)

I am using Google as my search engine in Chrome. I found that no matter what I input in the address bar, a suggestion will always pop up.

E.g. I input "sdf" in the address bar, hit entry, Chrome will use Google to find the result. It's what I expect, but a second later, there is an alert to ask me:

> Do you want to visit http://sdf/

This is getting really boring, because it's displayed every time. How can I fix it?

[image: chrome]

Comment: It's the same, but unfortunately, the answer of that question saying "changing DNS to google's" may not be useful in crazy China, since China often blocks google's DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:
Click on Wrench icon --> Options --> Under the hood --> Privacy --> Uncheck "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar"

Comment: I have unchecked that, but it still displayed every time