# Domain name without TLD

Tags: google-chrome, browser, dns

I typed securedrop into the Chrome address bar and pressed enter. In addition to querying Google as usual, Chrome showed me this:

[image]

Clicking that link (`http://securedrop/`) took me to a [parked domain page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1jHc.jpg). I checked if securedrop might be a new TLD, but it's not in the IANA list.

What's going on here?

Comment: `http://securedrop/` takes me nowhere in IE or Chorme here (can't resolve the IP).   Who are you using for DNS?  What was the URL shown once you got to the parked domain page?  If you ping "securedrop" or do an `NSLookup securedrop`, what IP is returned?

Comment: I attempted to browse to said link, in which case nothing appeared for me. There is a possibility that you may have a line in your hosts file for "securedrop" to re-route you to a parked domain.

Comment: This is what I see in Chrome: http://imgur.com/PNgi5FK. `ping` returns ``cannot resolve securedrop: Unknown host``. `nslookup` returns ``server can't find securedrop: NXDOMAIN``. `securedrop` doesn't appear in my `/etc/hosts/`.

Comment: Anything in `/etc/hosts.allow`?

Comment: No, that file doesn't exist.

Comment: easyDNS will happily print the name of anything you point to `216.220.40.248` (including through `/etc/hosts`) saying it's a parked domain. That's no mystery. The question is of course why Chrome thinks that host name points to that IP address.

Comment: The reason I asked about `hosts.allow` is because the Securedrop installer writes something to that file.

Comment: Related post: [How to make Chrome recognize one word queries as a search not a url](http://superuser.com/q/266049/820)  Sounds like your DNS provider (EasyDNS maybe?) is returning responses for the term you're searching for, so Chrome thinks it might be a real website.  Fix your DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was the DNS server. This happened when I was browsing through a SOCKS proxy via a server hosted at Digital Ocean. If I turn off the proxy server, this problem disappears.

Comment: That's kind of a horrible practice of a proxy. But if this is what solved your problem, you should click the green check mark to the left of the answer to mark it as the solution.